# Using Mongoose find() to select a value from a nested object

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Having the following JSON document stored in a MongoDB database.

```
{
   val1: 12
   val2: {
      num: 1,
      num2: 5
   }
}
```

I can use Mongoose its find() method to retrieve val1 as so:

```
Result.find().select({ val1: 1, _id: 0 })...
```

But how would I retrieve only num2 from the nested object val2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose select fields (nested)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120296/mongoose-select-fields-nested)

Comment: @Fcmam5 it does. Thank you.